# Serve clients with geospatial news

Tags: mongodb, indexing, geospatial

I am developing an app where the user will receive geo based information depending on his position. The server should be able to handle huge number of connected clients >100k.

Now i came up with 4 Approaches on how to handle the users position.

1. Approach - Without geospatial index:

   The app server does just hold a list of connected clients and they're location.
   Whenever there is a information available the server does loop over the whole list and checks whether the client is within a given radius.

   **Doubts**: Very expensive
2. Approach - Handle geospatial index in the app server:

   The app server does maintain a R Tree with all connected clients and they're location.
   Therefore i was looking at [JSI Java Spatial Index](http://jsi.sourceforge.net)

   **Doubts**: It is very expensive to update the geospatial index with JSI
3. Approach - Let the database "mongoDb" do the geospatial index / calculation:

   The app server does only hold a reference to the connected client (connection) and saves the key to that reference together with its location into mondoDb.
   When a new information is available the server can query the database to get the keys off all clients nearby.

   **Pro**: I guess mongoDb does have a much better implementation of geospatial indexes than i could ever do in the app server.

   **Doubts**: Clients are traveling around which forces me to update the geospatial index frequently. Can i do that or am i running into a performance problem?
4. Approach - Own "index" using 2 dimensional array

   Today i was thinking about creating a very simple index by using a two dimensional array. While the outer array is for the longitude the inner would be for the latitude.
   Lets say 3 longitude / altitude degree would be enough precision. 
   I could receive a list of users in a given area by

   ArrayList userList = data[91][35] //91.2548980712891, 35.60869979858;
   // i would also need to get the users in the surrounding arrays 90;35, 92;35 ...
   // if i need more precision i could use one more decimal data[912][356]

   **Pro**: I would have fast read and write access without a query to the database

   **Doubts**: Radius is shorter at poles. Ugly hack?

I would be very grateful if someone could point me into "the" right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The index used by MongoDB for geospatial indexing is based on a geohash, which essentially converts a 2 dimensional space into a one-dimensional key, suitable for B-tree indexing. While this is somewhat less efficient than an R-tree index it will be vastly more efficient than your scenario 1.  I would also argue that filtering the data at the db level with a spatial query will be more efficient and easier to maintain than creating you own spatial indexing strategy on top.

The main thing to be aware of with MongoDB is that you cannot use a geometry column as a shard key, though you can shard a collection containing a geometry field, using another key. Also, if you wish to do any aggregation queries, (which isn't clear from your question) the geometry field must be the first through the pipeline.

There is also a geohaystack index, which is based on small buckets and optimized for search based on small areas, see, http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/geohaystack/, which might be useful in your case.

As far as speed is concerned, insertion and search on a B-Tree index are essentially O(log n), see [Wikipedia B-Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree) while without an index your search will be O(n), so it will not take very long before the difference in perfomance is enormous between having and not having an index.

If you are concerned about heavy writes slowing things down, you can tune the [write concern in MongoDB](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/write-concern/) so that you don't have to wait for a majority of replicas to respond to every write (the default), but at the cost of potentially inconsistent data, if you should lose your master.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i guess a geohaystack index would fit for my case. Where the MongoDB doc didn't answer my question is how a update to the index would affect the performance and if it is a good idea to do that.

Comment: Ultimately, there is no substitute for testing, but even if an index has implications on write performance, this will be more than offset by read performance. With MongoDB you can tune what is known as the write concern, ie, writes will return sooner if you don't wait for a majority of replicas to respond, but at the cost of possibly inconsistent data if you were to lose your primary.

Comment: @user3211074. I have updated my answer with some info on B-Tree and write concern in Mongo, which might help answer you question.

Comment: I was going to ask for more info on your actual queries, so as to be better able to give a view on scenario 4, but see you have accepted the answer. Did you go for scenario 3, then?

Comment: I tried scenario 3 but the result from the performance test was not amazing. Today I tried scenario 4. It was quite simple with great performance. I used a hashMap with "long;lat" as key (rounded to 1 decimal) the value for that key is a list of connected users. It works perfect for my use case.